# Submitting a form with ajax while staying on sign up page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am new to AJAX.

I am trying to submit a form with ajax using the following logic:

```
//validate form

//if invalid never submit
//if valid, ajax request to get msg
   //get success html if no server side errors exist. Replace sign up page with success html
   //get fail message if server side errors exist, so the user can correct them (ex. invalid credit card no)
```

My AJAX:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
   if($(this).valid()) {

      $.ajax({
        url: 'formAction.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
           /*convert php variables to JavaScript ones*/
            if(success==true){
                 //relpace current page with confirmation
            }
            if(success==false){
                 //print out errors and allow user to re-submit
            }
        }                        
    });         

    }
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

I was wondering if I am on the right track with this implementation? or if this implementation is even possible?

I greatly appreciate any advice in making this implementation work.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need to get your form data in to a javascript variable to use with you [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and add `data: myFormData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
   if($(this).valid()) {

      $.ajax({
        url: 'formAction.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(), //You need to provide this, serialize may work here
        type: 'POST', //Added single quote to prevent unterminated string literal
        success: function(data){
           //call was successful since success message was called
        },//Don't forget closing curly brace on function
        error: function(data){
           //Specify a call back for errors
        }                        
    });         

    }
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this method get all the form data automatically or do I need to get it somehow using `data` in my ajax call or something? I would like to have access to my form vars in my action script using standard `$_POST` vars....

Comment: You still need to get the form data.

Comment: @MiGusta You need to add data

Comment: Can I just add it like `data: myForm` <- does myForm have to be an ID?

Comment: Last question, shouldn't e.preventDefault() prevent the default operation which is form submission, so `return false` would be unnecessary?

Comment: Your right go with e.preventDefault() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false